# How to retain ABI-compatibility, when converting methods to take references and const?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, elf

I'm working with a (shared) library, that in many places takes `string` by value, rather than reference. Also, although the functions don't modify the strings, they do not advertise their `const`-ness:

```
void logger(std::string);
```

I'd like to change these functions to:

```
void logger(const std::string &);
```

Seems easy, and any library-client will pick up the new interface without changing -- the A**P**I is preserved. But the A**B**I will change, and I'm worried about the existing library-clients, which will all require recompiling.

I don't want to maintain *copies* of the functions either -- just turn the old-style ones into wrappers around the new ones.

How can I have the newly-compiled clients use the new interface, while still allowing existing executables to find the shims implementing the old interface?

Or is bumping the library's version-number the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just version header files like this:

```
namespace boblib {
  inline namespace v2 {
    void logger(std::string_view);
  }
}
```

and don't expose `boblib::logger` to "v2" library users (ie, in public headers), but still export them.

"New" users of `boblib` see `boblib::logger` but its real name is `boblib::v2::logger`.

(Technically you don't need the `v2` in the case that you are always changing signatures, but ODR rule violations  are really easy without it (and making overload lookup work right when they are both visible is hard), so use it).

Inline namespaces where invented, at least partly, to solve this problem.

Comment: @mikhn yes.  I used `string_view` instead of `string const&` because you might as well do better.  That might have confused you.

Comment: It did confuse me, and your comment is not helping. "Do better"? The code has to work on RHEL6, where the stock compiler is g++ 4.4.7. There is no C++17. Let's not mix different things, shall we?

Comment: @mikh I do not know what is confusing. Yes, `BobLib::v2` contains the new methods.  Despite that, existing code compiled against new headers silently picks them up, because it is an `inline namespace`.  Old libraries (not recompiled, or using old headers) linking against it picks up the old function.  Everything works.

Comment: @miha if you are using ancient compilers, indicate which C++ standard you are using in the question with tags or mentioning it explicitly.  "Do better" refers to using `string_view` instead of `string const&`.  If your compiler is [tag:C++11] compiliant, then it will support `inline namespace`s.